# Can't set div height on IE 8

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

This is the website: http://mpn.p.ht/wp_br2/

I'm adding custom CSS to IE8, with `css_browser_selector.js` http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

In every rule where I want to target IE, I add the class `.ie` at first.

I'm using the last `<link>` CSS file name: `custom.css` to style, so that it overrides any other style.

Nevertheless, I can't set the height of a div with id `nav`. I would like to set the height of this div to 40px.

It's a WordPress customized theme. (I don´t think this is a problem).

You can check using F12 on IE8.

Thanks.

Comment: Where's your Doctype? It has to be first. Always.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: When it's not first the layout of your page is a roll of a die.

Comment: Ok, but it is there. At header.php

Comment: This Doctype: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> is in header.php.

I checked the source code of the page, it´s there.

Comment: No it's not. The first line of code is `<head>`. View the source of your website and you can see.

Comment: Ok. I removed the <head> tag from index.php. It seems to be ok. Will check the height of the div in IE8. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, the page got pretty messy, but the height of the div seems to be 40 px. :)

Comment: No problem. Also if you can, try to get rid of the two spaces at the top of the source. It can sometimes cause problems.

Comment: And use <!doctype html> instead. :p

Comment: @reisio That's not necessarily true. HTML5 isn't even completed yet (although everything I do is HTML5). :)

Comment: Thank you so very much :) @ MiniRagnarok

Comment: @MiniRagnarok: sure it is, and even if it weren't, almost anything would be a better choice than XHTML and/or Transitional

Comment: Just wondering, but why aren't you using something like [this](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet) instead of targeting divs with other style rules for IE with a class and js?